# Electric Field of a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

Is there a point in space where the electric field is half of the electric field on the surface of the sphere? I just got curious if it would be possible.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the two solutions and setting them equal to each other (times that factor of 1/2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the electric field of a sphere shows that

$$E = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}$$

for values of $r\ge R$.

Solving for $E(x) = \frac{E(R)}{2}$ you find $x = R\sqrt{2}$ - in other words, you need to move a distance $R(\sqrt{2}-1)$ from the surface for the field to be halved (minus 1 because you start at the surface...)